# Should I put "the" in the following sentence?

Tags: articles

Which one is correct?

> 1. "She is in eighth grade."

vs

> 2. "She is in **the** eighth grade."

Answer (score 2):

"She is in the eighth grade" is correct and common. You need an article because "grade" here is singular. You need "the" and not "an" because you are specifying one particularly grade that she is in: the eighth one. You must say "eighth" rather than "eight" because the noun here is "grade", and so you need an adjective, not another noun.

You could say, "She is in grade eight." This is a slightly out-of-date wording.

Comment: One hears the following used interchangeably in my neck of the woods (northeast US):  She's in eighth grade.  She's in the eighth grade. She's an eighth-grader. She's in grade eight.

Comment: @TimRomano Good point. "She's in eighth grade" is also common. You don't need the "the". It also occurs to me that when we identify a member of a numbered or otherwise coded set by putting the noun first, we don't use an article. "He's in room 234", not "He's in the room 234." "I registered for class MAT-101", not "I registered for the class MAT-101". Etc. But if you put the identifier first, we usually use an article. "It's on floor number 3", but "It's on the third floor".

Answer (score 1):

She is in (the) eighth grade is common. The is optional; we can omit it. Please refer to Oxford Learners Dictionary.

Answer (score 1):

"she is in eighth grade." and "she is in the eighth grade." are both correct.

Please note that I assumed the `eight` in your first sentence was a typo and should've been `eighth`. If it was deliberate, then the second sentence is the correct one.

The "the" is not necessary, though using it would not be wrong.